# How to add a field in edit post page inside Publish box in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to add a new checkbox field inside Publish block in add/edit post page. Does anyone have idea how to do that ?

Comment: Check this - >http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/more-fields/

Comment: I have checked more fields. Can't we just add a new field by some other way like add_meta_box() ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I have finally found the solution. I hope it will be of good use for somebody.

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'publish_in_frontpage' );
function publish_in_frontpage($post)
{
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_publish_in_frontpage', true);
    echo '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last">
         <span id="timestamp">'
         . '<label><input type="checkbox"' . (!empty($value) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null) . 'value="1" name="publish_in_frontpage" /> Publish to frontpage</label>'
    .'</span></div>';
}

function save_postdata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if(empty($postid) || $_POST['post_type'] != 'article' ) return false;

    if($_POST['action'] == 'editpost'){
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'publish_in_frontpage');
    }

    add_post_meta($postid, 'publish_in_frontpage', $_POST['publish_in_frontpage']);
}
```

Comment: Nice find. I had never thought of putting something in that box, but having the (somewhat undocumented) method of doing so is cool. Starred this for later use!

Comment: Just a small update: `publish_in_frontpage()` seems to get no parameters, so I used `global $post;` inside, works just fine.

Comment: This code is far from complete/correct and it's not working, I doubt it ever worked. I added my fixed/commented code below.

Comment: Does it still work in the latest WP5 ? It looks like the do_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions') is never triggered on my app.

Answer (score 16):

**rbncha**'s code didn't work out of the box and needed a lot of tweaking, the code below is what I came up with. I've added some comments which explains everything thoroughly.

The following code adds a checkbox in the publish block of posts (you can easily change the post type), and stores/retrieves the value in/from the database. With some minor tweaking you could easily add a text field or anything you like.

It should be noted that you have to change `my_` to a **unique key** for your theme or plugin!

```
add_action( 'post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'my_featured_post_field' );
function my_featured_post_field()
{
    global $post;

    /* check if this is a post, if not then we won't add the custom field */
    /* change this post type to any type you want to add the custom field to */
    if (get_post_type($post) != 'post') return false;

    /* get the value corrent value of the custom field */
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'my_featured_post_field', true);
    ?>
        <div class="misc-pub-section">
            <?php //if there is a value (1), check the checkbox ?>
            <label><input type="checkbox"<?php echo (!empty($value) ? ' checked="checked"' : null) ?> value="1" name="my_featured_post_field" /> Featured on frontpage</label>
        </div>
    <?php
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'my_save_postdata');
function my_save_postdata($postid)
{
    /* check if this is an autosave */
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;

    /* check if the user can edit this page */
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;

    /* check if there's a post id and check if this is a post */
    /* make sure this is the same post type as above */
    if(empty($postid) || $_POST['post_type'] != 'post' ) return false;

    /* if you are going to use text fields, then you should change the part below */
    /* use add_post_meta, update_post_meta and delete_post_meta, to control the stored value */

    /* check if the custom field is submitted (checkboxes that aren't marked, aren't submitted) */
    if(isset($_POST['my_featured_post_field'])){
        /* store the value in the database */
        add_post_meta($postid, 'my_featured_post_field', 1, true );
    }
    else{
        /* not marked? delete the value in the database */
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'my_featured_post_field');
    }
}
```

*If you want to read more about custom fields see here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Custom_Fields*

Comment: `check if the custom field is submitted`

You can add hidden field before checkbox with same name and value = 0.

Comment: That seems like bad practice? Hacky solution?

Comment: no — many-many frameworks do that. So this could be named as existing practice.

Answer (score 2):

Well!, I could not find a solution to add a field in **Publish Block**. For the temporary solution, I have added new block by simply adding simple codes like below.

`add_action( 'admin_init', 'category_metabox');`

```
//add new publish to frontpage box
add_meta_box( 
    'publish_in_frontpage',
    'Publish in Frontpage',
    'publish_in_frontpage_callback',
    'article',
    'side',
    'high'
);

function publish_in_frontpage_callback($post)
{
    $value = get_post_meta($post->ID, '_publish_in_frontpage', true);
    echo '<label><input type="checkbox"' . (!empty($value) ? ' checked="checked" ' : null) . 'value="1" name="publish_in_frontpage" /> Publish to frontpage</label>';
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_postdata');

function save_postdata($postid)
{   
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return false;
    if ( !current_user_can( 'edit_page', $postid ) ) return false;
    if(empty($postid) || $_POST['post_type'] != 'article' ) return false;

    if($_POST['action'] == 'editpost'){
        delete_post_meta($postid, 'publish_in_frontpage');
    }

    add_post_meta($postid, 'publish_in_frontpage', $_POST['publish_in_frontpage']);
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Use the [Advanced Custom Fields](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/) plugin for wordpress.

Comment: I don't find a way to add a checkbox inside **Publish** block in Advanced Custom Fields